# Change shape color based on value in mysql

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to animate or change a shape's color based on a value in mysql?
I want my shape to be:
green if room is empty
red if room is occupied

```
<div id="wb_Shape6"   style="position:absolute;left:471px;top:94px;width:204px;height:183px;filter:alpha(opacity=90);opacity:0.90;z-index:7;">
<img src="images/img0012.png" id="Shape6" alt="" style="width:204px;height:183px;"></div>
```

Comment: What server side language are you using to interpret the sql value?

Comment: @Vlad Bardalez I am using wamp server 2.4 and mysql as language I don't think I understand you well because I m just a beginner

Comment: From your other post I understand you are using PHP. I assume your query is working so can you echo the value you want to base the color change?

Comment: I slightly understand your point but can you explain it more thank you

Comment: With PHP you need to use query the data you want from you database. Then fetch the particular data you want to use to change the color. Then you can use an if statement to display different HTML elements based on the if statement.

Comment: can you give me a link on a similar example on how to integrate the "if" statement in html in div particularly as you see in the code ? thank you @Vlad Bardalez

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.
There are a lot of ways to do this. YOU will need to figure out what your SQL Query is going to look like. Since you have not posted a lot of data, a lot of us will be guessing. If you can add more examples or code to your question, we can help more.

So, I would advise this:

```
<style>
.myBox {
  position:absolute;
  left:471px;
  top:94px;
  width:204px;
  height:183px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=90);
  opacity:0.90;
  z-index:7;
}

.redBox {
  background: red;
}

.greenBox {
  background: green;
}
</style>
<?php
// perform MySQL Query (MySQLi or PDO)
// get results: $result, make a decision based on the condition
// will use MySQLi for example
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM someTable;")) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     if($row['room'] == "empty"){
       $colorClass = "greenBox";
     } else {
       $colorClass = "redBox";
     }
   }
   $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
<div id="wb_Shape6" class="myBox <?php echo $colorClass; ?>">
  <img src="images/img0012.png" id="Shape6" alt="" style="width:204px;height:183px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Twisty the code is pretty much the same as shown but I can add more if you tell me what are you looking for thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is regarded as a basic conditional situation. There are many ways to handle it. Here I will not deal with how the data will be coming from the data source. Suppose that you have a variable named `$status` and this variable has one of two values `0` or `1`.

In your example you are using inline styling so we may make an inline condition something like the following:

```
<div style="background-color:<?php echo ($status)? 'green':'red'; ?>;"></div>
```

Comment: could you give an example on how to use inline styling? thank you @sємsєм

Comment: What I have regarded in the answer is an example for [inline style](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) @GhassenCharai